# A transport-level error has occurred - The specified network name is no longer available. ( Azure Synapes )

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a two tables that I want to merge

Table A

| COL A | COL B | COL C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | value |
| 2 | 2 | value |

Table B

| COL A | COL B | COL C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | value |
| 2 | 2 | newvalue |

The merge SQL

```
MERGE INTO dbo.TableA AS target  
    USING dbo.TableB AS source 
    ON 
    (
        target.ColA = source.ColA AND
        target.ColB = source.ColB 
    )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
            target.COLC = source.COLC
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
            INSERT (COLA, COLB, COLC)  
            VALUES (source.COLA, source.COLB, source.COLC);
```

Whenever I run above code my database (Azure synapse, dedicated pool) throws following error, and then stops responding for about 20 seconds.

"A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)"

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with the Update part of the merge. because the first time I run the statement
(where there isn't any data inside table A) It works just fine and inserts the two rows. But if I run it again it fails with the transport-level error

Comment: I suggest you contact customer support.  There is a chance that the server process is dumping and closing the connection.  (perhaps due to a bug)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timeout, if you're using Sql Server Management Studio, you can try extending:

[image: Timeout settings]

Your post doesn't indicate what client you're using - if it's .NET code, probably want to set a `CommandTimeout` on your connection or query.

If that doesn't work, perhaps extending the query execution timeout if it's not already zero:

[image: Timeout settings (2)]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, and extending the transaction time-out unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Added one more timeout to look at.

Comment: The execution time-out is at 0 - It throws the error even if it's just two rows I'm trying to merge, so I don't think it's a timeout issue.

Comment: I wanted to exhaust that possibility given your statement that it stops responding for 20 seconds.